# How to tag correctly in GA4?

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-migration, eventtrigger

can´t retrieve monetizacion info from ga4 account
i've managed many GA4 accounts of some customers  and in one of them, can´t retrieve monetizacion info from purchases

for example, in one of my customer i've set in gtm a new tag of this way:

new label
type: GA4 Label
Config label: GA4
event name: {{Event}}

aditional settings:
check in "send ecommerce data "
data font: "Data Layer"

trigger:
type: custom
event name: view_item|view_item_list|select_item|add_to_cart|remove_from_cart|view_cart|begin_checkout|add_payment_info|add_shipping_info|purchase
check the box "use regular expression"

and in the GA4 account i can found PURCHASE event properly configured

Doing same in another customer, the PURCHASE event not shown:

I've configured same TAG with same triggers in GTM